# How can I increase the output voltage without changing the motor and turbine design?

Tags: voltage, motor, output, input, gear

I made a small hydropower project for school. Water flow rate is too low. I attached 24 V DC gear motor. The output is 4 V. How can I increase it?

I can not change the turbine dimensions and motor and I cannot increase the flow rate. How I can the increase 4V at the output by attaching some component at the output?

Comment: Transformer if is going about BLDC motor. If brushed use step-up converter.

Comment: Normally, the entire turbine blade shape, root to tip, and physical surrounding system is ***designed*** from the ground up for the water flow rate -- and most especially the ***head***. There is a spectrum of designs spanning from low head to high head, and in between. See *kaplan*, *francis*, & *pelton*. Only then does one select the generator, gearing, etc. You are stuck with the important stuff that matters, it seems, that you are told you cannot change. Not a good situation unless what you are forced to use is in the right ballpark of the head and flow rate you are also given.

Comment: You need to put a load on the 4 volt output and see how much current you can take before the 4 volts drops down 2 volts. Then you need to decide whether that is enough electrical power for your needs. If not, then it won't work.